How to make a file available for download
I am developing a chrome extension. It sends some json data to rest api and then gets 'pdf' file as response. I want to make this file available for download using chrome api (chrome.downlaods.download).
I couldn't find a way to do so.
This code is part of background.js
function downloadReportClicked() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(["randomKey"], function (result) {
    //console.log("currentSavings: ", currentSavings);
    console.log("result", result.randomKey);

    fetch("https://localhost:44334/GetPdf", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(result.randomKey),
    })
      .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then((arrayBuffer) => {
        console.log("Web request successful:", arrayBuffer);
        handlePdfResponse(arrayBuffer);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error making web request:", error);
      });
  });
}

As suggest by blackbox.ai I used this code
function handlePdfResponse(arrayBuffer) {
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: "application/pdf" });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  console.log(url)
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = "abc.pdf";
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}


Below code is part of rest api that sends accepts request and sends response to the client.
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
 pdfServiceObj = new PdfService();
 try
 {
     PdfDocument document = pdfServiceObj.CreatePdf((JsonArray)userData["data"]);
     httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         document.Save(ms);
         byte[] pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();
         httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfBytes);
         httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
         httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
         {
             FileName = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()
         };
     }
     return Ok(httpResponseMessage);
 }

The error I get is window is not defined. If I exclude window I get URL.createObjectURL is not a function.
I need help in resolving this issue.
I tried using webkit.URL, window.URL, went through chrome extension developers api but didn't find enough example source code. Asked chatgpt, bard, perplexit and blackbox.ai.
I am expecting code that makes the file downloadable automatically upon receiving response from rest api.

Download pdf programmatically or download pdf from url best approach  or How do I download a PDF file using a URL link to local computer in c#
